# Is `string` a default `type` of a Terraform `variable`?

Tags: terraform

I can't find the answer in [the docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#type-constraints), hence the question in the title. Are the following `variable` declarations equivalent?

```
variable "a" {
  nullable = false
  type     = string
}
variable "b" {
  nullable = false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's stated in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#type-constraints) you shared:

> If no type constraint is set then a value of any type is accepted.

So basically variable `b` is set to any type.

Comment: "stated in the documentation " -  a link would be helpful.